# How to send image to Zebra printer memory?

Tags: api, printing, zpl-ii

I have a Zebra GK420t printer. I want to print some stickers width an image on it, but when I use the API that zebra provides for Linux an error appears in the console.

"Invalid OS"

Sometimes appears other error.

"Could not open device using implicit connection string, attempted TCP:Zebra_Technologies_ZTC_GK420t:9100"

or

"Invalid arguments length".

For now, for me its imposible to use that API...

Any suggestion? Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm trying to use this command:

"java -jar ZSDK_API.jar graphic -n somePic.png -p Zebra_Technologies_ZTC_GK420t -d"

Comment: Someone else can help me?

Comment: I don't know that the Zebra API supports USB on Linux.  I believe it relies on Windows driver functionality.  Actually, I also don't think that model printer is *officially* supported in their Java SDK.  If this is the SDK that you are using, note that it does not support the GK series printer: http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html#mainpartabscontainer_794f=downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using TCP, as indicated by your connection string.  However, your connection string also suggests you might be using USB since the name you have provided seems to be a Zebra driver name.  Anyways, assuming TCP, you can use the printer's IP address and might have more luck:

**tcp:192.168.0.1:9100**

Also note that the Linux API doesn't support USB.  The SDK requires a Windows driver for USB communication.  Zebra's newest API also doesn't technically support your printer, but the languages are very similar and it would be worth testing it out.

If the API doesn't work for your circumstances, you could look into the [ZPL Manual](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/zpl_manual.pdf) **~dg** command (page 174) to see how to download graphics, but honestly the API would be far easier to use.

Comment: My Zebra printer model doesn't have network connection. So I think that I need read the manual... Thanks anyway.

Comment: is zebra browserprint the only way to get a USB based printer onto port 9100? Or is there some other way? (I see blog entries on their site talking about sending raw data to port 9100 and some of them are referring to USB printers - but that doesn't work for us. Browserprint seems to use a rest interface)